# app-engine patch - how do Iget Django system error messages in foreign languages?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

Bonjour, Guten Morgen, Merhaba etc etc

Has anyone used foreign languages with app-engine-patch?
I am on version 1.1

In settings.py I have:
.......

## Enable I18N and set default language

USE_I18N = True
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'tr'

## Restrict supported languages (and JS media generation)

LANGUAGES = (
    ('tr', 'Turkish'),
    ('en', 'English'),
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'ragendja.middleware.ErrorMiddleware',
etc...
and I can see several folders on my Windows XP development box with names like:
....\conf\locale\tr\LC_MESSAGES

but the error messages are still coming out in English.

Maybe I should contact the author of app-engine-patch to check localization is supported? But first can anyone see anything I may have done wrong or forgotten to do?

Regards

Geoff

Answer (score 1):

app-engine-patch was working perfectly. It was my testing that was at fault. I had not adjusted the preferred language setting on my browser, so it was still preferring the English error messages.

Now how do I say 'doh' in multiple languages?